# I cannot consume Spring Boot Thymeleaf endpoints with ajax

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am creating a simple crud system using spring boot + thymeleaf.

I am stuck before I can not consume my spring endpoints with a simple ajax.

**Controller**

```
@Controller
public class StudentController {
  
   @Autowired
    private StudentService service;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
        List<Student> liststudent = service.listAll();
        model.addAttribute("liststudent", liststudent);
        System.out.print("Get / "); 
        return "index";
    }

}
```

**index.html**

```
function getall()
{
    $.ajax({

        url:"http://localhost:8080/Student/list",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
       success:function(data)
       {
          console.log(data);
       }
    });

}
```

I get a JSON error in web console.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: #1 could you hit directly to **/save** using postman or curl ? Check this [cURL – POST request](https://mkyong.com/spring/curl-post-request-examples/) #2 Persist a row in database is a common task, so could you simplify your app and share it in github?

Comment: sir can i have you email

Comment: sir therreeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee

Comment: i will send my project to your email. i don't know to github

Comment: i cannot chat  it will not allow me to chat that room. provide the email to that room

Comment: there sirrrrrrrrrrrrrr

Comment: create an account here https://gist.github.com/ and upload file by file

Comment: ok sir i will upload and send the link

Comment: try to upload a simplified version. Just to try! And or try to earn git and how to use github https://medium.com/@sauravbhagat_10426/how-to-upload-code-to-github-6db1c8ff56aa

Comment: https://github.com/raguram1986/ragu

Comment: i uploaded i put project as ragu   github.com/raguram1986/ragu

Comment: github.com/raguram1986/ragu

Comment: sir i want the update project i downloaded the project it is not working

Comment: thank you sirrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Thymeleaf is a **server rendering framework**, so ajax is not one of your priorities.
- Thymeleaf + spring boot, returns html in any invocation.
- If you want to load some data using javascript (ajax), your spring must expose another endpoints which returns a valid json response.
- Decouple your spring controllers in two: views and rest endpoints

**Rest Endpoints**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("Student")
public class StudentController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<Student> listStudents() {
    List<Student> liststudent = service.listAll();
    return liststudent;
}
```

**Html Endpoints(spring + thymeleaf)**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping({ "/", "/index" })
public class ViewController {

@GetMapping
public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
    return "index";
}
```

- assets must be inside src/main/resources/static folder if you are using thymeleaf framework